# How to FETCH ALL RECORS and UPDATE RECORD in one to many mapping in SPRING DATA JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have created two simple modal entities Book and Author and an author has many books. The mapping is working and when I save author along with book abjects from postman it gets saved according in both tables but when I hit query for fetching all authors or all books it does not respond.
Is it something related to DTOs? How can I fetch the data, I don't want to use Join Query etc.
Please guide.[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images, copy the actual code and format it using markdown instead.

Comment: When something related to databases comes to a full stop most of the times locks are the problem. Check what blocking locks are present in your database.

Comment: I think you might be stuck in nested DTO loop. Please share the logs

Answer (score 0):

`@OneToMany` has parameter `FetchType(Enumeration) fetch`. It be `FetchType.LAZY` by default, you should change it to `FetchType.EAGER`. If parameter fetch is `FetchType.LAZY` Hibernate doesn't get Book entities until you call it. If fetch is `FetchType.EAGER` than Hibernate gets Book entities if you didn't call it.